# Extra space in string on mat-option

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor

When I get text from `mat-option` there is extra space at the end of the string, so my assertion fails when I compare this value with expected.

I've never had this problem before, how can I solve it, and why is this happening?

Comment: Use `.trim()` before/in assertion. Or provide your code to see why and when white spaces appears

Comment: @CzescTuSlawomr: please provide the actual code that fails. Include all details, that are necessary to reproduce and understand the problem.
('I've never had this problem before' is not actually helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with trimming:

```
element.getText().trim();
```

Then the value become without additional spaces and you can do your assertions as needed